# Rails 3 way to change content of element depending on current url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `link_to` that produces `<a href="#" id="login">Log in</a>`.

I'd like to change that to `<a href="/signup">Sign up</a>` when the url is on my log in page (as opposed to my homepage).

Is there a way to do this with Rails? I know I could use JavaScript but it was pointed out to me that it would make more sense to do this on the server-side.

I tried a `<% if request.url == "/login" %>` but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `request.url` will return the entire URL so it won't match '/login'. You could either parse the '/login' value from the `request.url` string or use `request.path`.

Here's a link that gives more info on getting parts of the current URL - http://programming-tut.blogspot.com/2010/06/ruby-on-rails-request-url.html